# Json Array - Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I try to get data from json array

```java
String username = object.getJSONObject("items").getString("f");
```

But it gives me a error

```
"items.f" not found.
```

Below is the Json Array.

```json
{
    "items": [
       {
           "s": "0",
           "f": "monems",
           "m": "ustad"
       },
       {
           "s": "0",
           "f": "monems",
           "m": "There?"
       },                      
       {
           "s": "0",
           "f": "monems",
           "m": "What&#039;s going on ?"
       },                      
       {
           "s": "2",
           "f": "monems",
           "m": "Sent at 4:03AM May 20th"
       }        
    ]
}
```

Comment: JSONArray items=object.getJSONArray("items");
     for(int i=1;i<=items.length();i++){
      
      String f=items.getString("f");
      
     }

Comment: Thanks @Signare. it gives me error when i use String f = items.getString("f"); "The method getString(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)".

Comment: JSONObject jsonObj=items.getJSONObject(i);
               String s=jsonObj.getString("s");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this -

```
JSONArray items=object.getJSONArray("items");
for(int i=1;i<=items.length();i++){
    JSONObject jsonObj=items.getJSONObject(i); 
    String s=jsonObj.getString("f");

}
```

Comment: loop should probably be from 0 to `items.length() - 1`.